# ¿Cómo usar getElementsByTagName en la consola de Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html5, dom, google-chrome

Obtengo un arreglo vacío cuanto pongo lo siguiente:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Sin embargo si selecciono un elemento con la opción de inspeccionar y después vuelvo a poner `document.getElementsByTagName("input");` esta vez ya no me devuelve un arreglo vacío, esta vez sí contiene todos los inputs que son parte de la página.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo usar `document.getElementsByTagName("input");` y que funcione sin necesidad de usar la opción de inspeccionar?

> Esto no me pasa en todas las páginas, solamente en algunas.

Comment: ¿Dónde ejecutas `document.getElementsByTagName("input");` en tu código? Podría ser que esté vacío porque lo ejecutes antes de que se hayan cargado los `input`  en el DOM (y por eso sí funcionaría desde la consola.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El DOM permite anidar elementos, es decir, tienes un objeto document, que incluye otros objetos document, como es el caso de una página que incluye un iframe.

En la consola de Chrome, justo a un lado del botón de borrado de la consola, está el selector de "ámbito". Ahí puedes seleccionar el elemento que incluya el document de tu interés.  Los detalles se encuentran [Elegir el contexto de ejecución](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/?hl=es#execution-context), de lo cual cabe destacar la siguiente imagen donde se resalta el selector mencionado previamente.

[image]

Relacionado

- [Debugging iframes with Chrome developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3275816/1595451)

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente la consola de chrome te permite hacer estas funciones siempre y cuando todos los atributos de la pagina esten guardados en la cache, si tu pagina no guarda correcta o completamente en tu pagina esta función de chrome no se activara hasta que inspecciones y los datos se guarden en cache(por esto te sirve en unas paginas y en otras no)

La opción mas sencilla que creo pueda servir, intenta con esto

Crea función en javascript

```
function tagname()
{
  document.getElementsByTagName("input");
}
```

Así te permitira consultar lo que necesites, tan solo llamando la función tagname (o como la llames) desde la consola de chrome(u otro navegador)

te dejo información sobre getElementsByTagName

Saludos

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp

Answer (score -1):

Perdón  la intención es que aprendas, quieres localizar un elemento en el formulario, si es así vas por mal camino, te conviene usar document.getElementById() y le pongas id a los tags , desde ya si no respondo a tú pregunta , mil perdones, capas lo que quieres es inventar un nuevo jquery.

En cuanto a la consola de Chrome, fíjate que al escribir document(dot) te auto completa y lista las funciones . en particular el método por el que preguntas si hay varios "input" te retornara un listado, por lo lo deberás de recorrer y encontrar el adecuado.  Puedes hacer

```
var arr=document.getElementByTagName("input");
```

y luego:
arr es una variable alocada en el navegador.
 que apropósito puedes usar mientras no recargues la página.

Comment: Esta respuesta se va por la ramas. La parte principal de la pregunta es acerca del uso de la consola de Chrome, pero no mencionas nada al respecto. En relación a la recomendación que das, falta que expliques por qué conviene usar ese método y poner id a los tags.